# sed group matching

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to do a bit of group matching using sed.

Basically I have something like this:

```
func_name(4234,43543,76,1)
```

And I need to match the parameters of the function:

```
$ echo 'func_name(4234,43543,76,1)' | sed -n 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1 /p' 
func_name(4234 

$ echo 'func_name(4234,43543,76,1)' | sed -n 's/\([[:digit:]]+\).*/\1 /p'
<empty>

$  echo 'func_name(4234,43543,76,1)'| sed -n 's/.*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1 /p' 
1
```

Comment: Do you know how many parameters?  Do you need to handle expressions like `34 + 45`?  Do you need to handle nested parentheses like `func_name(abs(b), sqrt(c), hypot(sqrt(d*e + f*g), abs(h-4)), 1)`?

Comment: 4 parameters, unsigned integers

Comment: OK: a fixed known number of simple arguments is relatively straight-forward.  Expressions without parentheses are only marginally harder; nested parentheses, possibly with commas in the argument lists, is a whole different ball-game, and not one to attempt with regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the number of parameters and they are always 'simple' (no nested parentheses and hence no embedded commas either), then:

```
echo "func_name(4234,53543,76,1)" |
sed 's/.*(\([^,)]*\),\([^,)]*\),\([^,)]*\),\([^,)]*\))/a1 \1; a2 = \2; a3 = \3; a4 = \4/'
```

Note that this tolerates spaces after the commas (and before them too - but you wouldn't leave spaces before, would you?).

Or, if the parameters are simple unsigned integers and you know the function name, maybe:

```
echo "func_name(4234,53543,76,1)" |
sed 's/func_name(\([0-9]*\), *\([0-9]*\), *\([0-9]*\), *\([0-9]*\))/a1 \1; a2 = \2; a3 = \3; a4 = \4/'
```

To get all the parameters in a single match, you have to do nested grouping:

```
echo "func_name(4234,53543,76,1)" |
sed 's/func_name(\(\([0-9]*\), *\([0-9]*\), *\([0-9]*\), *\([0-9]*\)\))/args = \1/'
```

Now `\2` .. `\5` still refer to the separate arguments.

```
echo "func_name(4234,53543,76,1)" |
sed 's/func_name(\(\([0-9]*\)\(, *\([0-9]*\)\)\{3\}\))/args = \1/'
```

This uses the repeat control `\{3\}` to find the arguments after the first.

Comment: yeah, I know, but I thought I could solve it with only one group and iterate in a loop to get \1 \2 \3 \4.

Comment: last one is not correct since you're matching on the comma also

Comment: Last two both worked for me...but I was expecting them to include the commas.  If you want the arguments in a single capture, you're going to have to include the commas.  If you want four separate arguments, you have to request four separate captures.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'func_name(4234,43543,76,1)' | cut -d "(" -f2 | sed 's/[,)]/ /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo 'func_name(4234,43543,76,1)' | sed 's/[^0-9,]//g;y/,/ /'
4234 43543 76 1
```

Or more verbosely:

```
echo 'func_name(4234,43543,76,1)' | 
sed 'h;s/[^0-9,]//g;y/,/\n/;x;s/(.*/ parameters are:/;G'
func_name parameters are:
4234
43543
76
1
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the option `-r` (extended regular expressions option) if you want to use the `[[:digit:]]` character class.